# Use a environment variable in the spring property file

Tags: java, spring, properties, environment-variables

I am new to `spring`  I have a `awsCredentials.properties` file.

```
AWS.Access.ID=value
AWS.Secret.ID=value
```

Now, I have already system environment variables in which I defined all the credentials. Now I want to use this is in the  `awsCredentials.properties` file. So that Whenever I commit, then this credentials should not be in the git . But when I try to do it like -

```
AWS.Access.ID=${AWS_ACCESSKEY}  this is not working.
```

can any one help me with this ?

Comment: What you have here should work just fine, assuming that you have an environment variable named AWS_ACCESSKEY

Comment: Is this a git question or a Spring question?  What version of Spring are you using?  Can you post the Spring code that is causing problems?

Comment: Its a spring question. Code is just a properties file in which , I have aws credentials.

Comment: Using 3.2.2.RELEASE spring version.

Comment: Did you happen to solve this

Answer (score 0):

as of now (May 2019) you can simply add the following:

```
AWS.Access.ID=${env.AWS_ACCESSKEY}
```

And spring should automagically read the value from the system environment. (at least it did for me without doing anything special in my config bean)